# Get list of object with matching property

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Person> listOfPerson=new List<Person>();
listOfPerson.Add(new Person(){Name="Pramod"});
listOfPerson.Add(new Person(){Name="Prashant"});
listOfPerson.Add(new Person(){Name="Sachin"});
listOfPerson.Add(new Person(){Name="Yuvraj"});
listOfPerson.Add(new Person(){Name="Virat"});
```

I want a LINQ Solution which will return list of object whose Name property starts with "**pra**"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var results = listOfPerson.Where(
    p => p.Name.StartsWith("pra", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

foreach(Person p in results)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomas's solution uses the LINQ extension methods, this uses the full LINQ query syntax.

```
var query = from x in listOfPerson 
            where x.Name.StartsWith("pra")
            select x;

foreach(var p in query)
{
    ...
}
```